# Correct way to write Subqueries MYSQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to list the employees who have a greater total hours worked then the average hours worked of all the employees

I feel that I've set up the query correctly but the only thing I'm not sure about is how to write sub queries.

```
SELECT 
    e.emp_id 'Employee ID', 
    e.emp_name 'Employee Name', 
    SUM(a.hrs_w) 'Total Hours Worked'
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN action a
on e.emp_id = a.emp_id
GROUP BY e.emp_id
WHERE SUM(a.hrs_w) >
                (SELECT (SUM(action.hrs_w) / COUNT(DISTINCT action.emp_id))
                    FROM action)
ORDER BY e.emp_id ASC;
```

i've test the subquery by itself and it works fine, it returns the value I'm after.

its just when i put the query within the brackets for the subquery i get a syntax error.

Comment: you know that feeling when you wait 10 minutes to be able to post again on overflow and then the moment you post you figure out that your using a where instead of a having and you feel really stupid.....**thats me right now**

Comment: If you think you found out the issue by yourself, put it as the accepted answer please.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was using a WHERE when i should be using a HAVING

```
HAVING SUM(a.hrs_w) >
            (SELECT (SUM(action.hrs_w) / COUNT(DISTINCT action.emp_id))
                FROM action)
```